# How to run all the classes in a single instance in Selenium RC?

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-rc

I am using Selenium RC in C#. I have list of .cs files, Is there any way to execute all the files without opening multiple instance.

Comment: what do you mean by multiple instances? Is that multiple browsers?

Comment: Yes! Each Execution its opening Selenium RC and browser, if i run number of .cs files its opening lot of tabs in my task bar currently i am using selenium.stop() command to handle this. but i am looking for a way to continue with the same session. 
Thoughts please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the same session per *.cs file use the `[TestFixtureSetUp]` attribute instead of the `[SetUp]` attribute when starting Selenium.

```
    [TestFixtureSetUp]
    public void SetupTest()
    {
        selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://change-this-to-the-site-you-are-testing/");
        selenium.Start();
        verificationErrors = new StringBuilder();
    }
```

This will run at the beginning of the File before any of the tests and then to kill it off put it in your `[TestFixtureTearDown]`

```
    [TestFixtureTearDown]
    public void TeardownTest()
    {
        try
        {
            selenium.Stop();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            // Ignore errors if unable to close the browser
        }
        Assert.AreEqual("", verificationErrors.ToString());
    }
```

And then you can move tests from their individual files per test to 1 file per bit of functionality that you wish to test.

Comment: Note: this is not related to the Selenium libraries, but rather the nUnit libraries used for executing the individual selenium tests.